# How do I create a trigger with many-to-many relationship?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My task is to add 10 to salary when an employee has a new education

This is my trigger now:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t BEFORE INSERT
ON mydb.employee_has_edu FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE mydb.employee
SET employee.salary = employee.salary + 10
```

The database schema looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer was actualy pretty easy:

```
DROP TRIGGER if exists t;
CREATE TRIGGER t AFTER INSERT
ON mydb.employee_has_edu FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE mydb.employee
SET employee.salary = employee.salary + 10
WHERE employee.id_employee = NEW.id_emp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are quite close the solution but with your trigger you'd update all the employees salaries when someone added a new education.

```sql
UPDATE mydb.employee
SET employee.salary = employee.salary + 10
where id_employee = :new.id_employee
```

I would also prefer to use AFTER INSERT trigger instead BEFORE INSERT. BEFORE INSERT use to be to protect integrity restrictions against inconsistent data but AFTER INSERT use to be to apply bussines rules.